# PHP How to add editor to a new page

Tags: php

i want to add an editor(see [pic http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/7664/editorw.jpg](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/7664/editorw.jpg) attach) to a my webpage. How can i do that?!

Comment: sorry the attached picture didn't make it ...

Comment: maybe giving an URL with an example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

the editor you have in your screenshot is somekind of FCK Editor. you can download [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/download) (the new version of FCKEditor) and use the following code to create an editor in your pages:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>    
<textarea cols="80" id="editor2" name="editor2" rows="10">&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a 

href="http://www.fckeditor.net/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[

                    // This call can be placed at any point after the
                    // <textarea>, or inside a <head><script> in a
                    // window.onload event handler.

                    // Replace the <textarea id="editor"> with an CKEditor
                    // instance, using default configurations.
                    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2' );

                //]]>
                </script>
```

make sure you include the valid path to `ckeditor.js` also you can consult the [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration) for more details.

Also make sure you have cleaning code for user input (like white list of tags) because  if you don't your site is going to be vunerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about HTML editor, then check out [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) :)

Comment: yep can you add a sample how to create it with php ^^